# Можно ли динамически определить, как был создан объект - на куче или в стеке?

Tags: c++

Например проверять объект при очищении контейнера:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    vector<string*> vec;
    vec.push_back(new string{"ptr1"});
    vec.push_back(new string{"ptr2"});
    string str1{"nonptr1"};
    string str2{"nonptr2"};
    vec.push_back(&str1);
    vec.push_back(&str2);

    for(auto* s : vec) {
        cout << *s << endl;
        delete s; //На третьем элементе очевидно всё повалится
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Есть ли стандартные механизмы определения, каким способом создан объект?

Comment: Наверное исходя из адреса можно узнать. Правда нужно знать какое адресное пространство у стека.

Comment: Хотя ещё может быть константный объект, который находится в константной области памяти и например глобальный объект, который тоже может находится в 4й области.

Comment: По идее, можно "обойти" кучу, и так выяснить, есть ли обьект в куче. Процесс довольно длительный... Лучше куда-то вносить отметку о куче, или использовать "умные" указатели...

Comment: Стек... с ассемблером можно узнать границы текущего стекового окна. По сохранённым окнам... Где-то видел примеры стак-трейса. Подняв стак-трейс можно получить минимум и максимум "стека", а по-ним вычислить в стеке переменные или нет. Для однопоточности будет работать...

Comment: "Стандартного" - т.е. переносимого, в рамках языка - пути нет. Можно, конечно, для конкретной машины отслеживать адреса в стеке и в куче, но это будет все равно не гарантированно.  

Другое дело, что есть возможность запретить создавать объекты динамически, или наоборот, в стеке.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Если в контейнере - указатели, контейнер просто освободит выделенную им память (но не память, куда они указывают)...

Comment: @Harry запретить с помощью приватизации конструкторов и разрешения только статического метода-фабрики?

Comment: @magrif Ну да, где-то так :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определить , что адрес в стеке можно с помощью проверки адреса:

```
bool  isInStack(void * x) {
  volatile  bool  stacktop  ;
  return  x > ( & stacktop ) ; 
}
```

Но проблема с другими адресами: глобальных переменных. У них адреса не в стеке , а в куче. И определить, что нужно удалять или нельзя придётся вручную, задавая вектор структуры с флагом , что нужно удалить. Данный способ определять место информации , что оно стеке очень ИНДИВИДУАЛЬНЫЙ. Это называется ХАКИНГ. Где-то работает, а где-то нет.
Например, в многопотоковой программе у каждого потока **свой** стек и если проверять указатель у переменной **другого** потока, то один поток скажет это в его стеке, другой - нет.

Comment: Почему волатайл бул переменная это вершина стэка?

Comment: @magrif : потому,что все переменные методов до этой функции не теряются, а хранятся в стеке. А новый вызов функции `clear` добавляет в стек ещё новые данные. Адрес `stacktop` это НЕ адрес вершины, а всего-лишь граница, по которой МОЖНО доказать , что переменная в стеке.

Comment: А почему эта граница volatile  bool, а не, допустим, unsigned long? Что за функция clear?

Comment: `bool` меньше размером, а нужна любая переменная. `clear` это старое название функции, которая должна была удалять элементы вектора. Я уже назвал по-другому.

Comment: т.е. ключевое слово volatile здесь роли не играет?

Comment: `volatile` используется в случаях, где в коде не видно прямое использование переменной, не устанавливаете значение и не считываете. Это прямой вызов для оптимизации компиляторов вообще удалить эту переменную. Знак переменной `volatile` указывает компилятору делать что положено, а не умничать.

Comment: Можно добавить,  что подобные функции нужно делать раздельно компилируемыми, чтобы исключить возможность оптимизации компилятором (т.е. заставить его сгенерить код создания  нового фрейма в стеке).  И с учетом этого замечания размер переменной `stacktop` значения не имеет.

Answer (score 8):

Тут сам подход неверный, если у вас есть пачка указателей на объекты, память для которых была выделена разными способами, то надо хранить и пачку соответствующих функций для их деаллокации. Проверка, лежит объект в куче или на стеке в данном случае никак не поможет; например у вас есть динамический аллокатор использующий буфер на стеке в качестве хранилища вместо кучи.

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать такого рода обёртку, где будет динамически во время исполнения определяться, как был создан объект (на стеке или в куче), с помощью виртуального полиморфизма.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::unique_ptr;

class PtrDeallocationWrapper {
public:
    virtual ~PtrDeallocationWrapper() {}
};

template <class T>
class PtrDeallocationWrapperOnHeap
        : public PtrDeallocationWrapper
{
public:
    template <class... Args>
    PtrDeallocationWrapperOnHeap(Args&&... args)
        : ptr_(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {}
    virtual ~PtrDeallocationWrapperOnHeap() {
        cout << "heap deallocation" << endl;
    }

private:
    unique_ptr<T> ptr_;
};

template <class T>
class PtrDeallocationWrapperOnStack
        : public PtrDeallocationWrapper
{
public:
    PtrDeallocationWrapperOnStack(T * ptr) : ptr_(ptr) {}
    virtual ~PtrDeallocationWrapperOnStack() {
        cout << "stack not deallocation" << endl;
    }

private:
    T * ptr_;
};

template <class T, class... Args>
auto make_heap_ptr(Args&&... args)
    -> unique_ptr<PtrDeallocationWrapper>
{
    return std::move(unique_ptr<PtrDeallocationWrapper>(
                         new PtrDeallocationWrapperOnHeap<T>
                            (std::forward<Args>(args)...))
                     );
}

template <class T>
auto make_stack_ptr(T* ptr)
    -> unique_ptr<PtrDeallocationWrapper>
{
    return std::move(unique_ptr<PtrDeallocationWrapper>(
                         new PtrDeallocationWrapperOnStack<T>(ptr))
                     );
}

int main() {
    vector<unique_ptr<PtrDeallocationWrapper> > vec;

    vec.push_back(make_heap_ptr<string>("lol"));
    string str1 = "kek";
    vec.push_back(make_stack_ptr<string>(&str1));

    vec.pop_back();
    vec.pop_back();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это уже немного из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно?" :)

Answer (score 1):

Например так, если конечно Вы имеете доступ к коду:

```
#define onHeap 0b11111111

struct A
{
    unsigned char placement;

    void *operator new(size_t size)
    {

        void* ptr = malloc(size);
        static_cast<A*>(ptr)->placement = onHeap;

        return ptr;
    }
};
```

Проверяем, где находится объект, так:

```
instance_of_A.placement == onHeap;
```

Для объектов класса A, если он в хипе, область памяти под placement будет заполнена единицами. Если где-то ещё - скорее всего какой-нибудь мусор. Но конечно нужно помнить, что может возникнуть случайность, когда на стеке под placement будут одни единичные биты.

Только не нужно путать. До конструирования объекта класса, его там нет, по сути. Просто мы заранее в нужное место записываем определенное значение, а при конструировании нужно сделать так, чтобы его не переписать, т.е. важно написать конструктор класса так, чтобы он не перезаписал область памяти под placement.