# Закрытие изменения объекта по указателю из поля класса и информация о месте хранения объекта

Tags: c++, классы, smart-pointer, access-control

Хочу в экземпляре класса B хранить ссылку на экземпляр класс A

```
class A
{
    int i;
    // много полей и методов
};

class B
{
public:
   A& a_ref;
   // много других полей и методов

   B(const A&/*, другие аргументы*/)
};

A a(/*аргументы*/);
B b(a/*, аргументы*/);
```

Да таким образом, чтобы сам по себе `a` был изменяемым, а через `b` доступа к изменению `a` не было. Напрашивается, чтобы в `B` была ссылка в виде:

```
class B
{
public:
   const A& a_ref;
   // много других полей и методов

   B(const A&/*, другие аргументы*/)
};
```

Однако, допустим, я хочу, чтобы у объекта класса `B` я мог менять `a_ref`, а данные внутри `a_ref` - нет. Тогда, очевидно, нужно сделать так:

```
class B
{
public:
   A const *a_ref;
   // много других полей и методов

   B(const A& A_/*, другие аргументы*/) : a_ref(&A_) {}
};
```

Вопрос: **нужно ли мне использовать умные указатели?**

Comment: задавайте один вопрос в вопросе. для вопроса 1 нет контекста, а вопрос 2 дубликат

Comment: Стек понятие растяжимое. Например `void f(void){std::stack<A> s;...}`. Нужна причина для каких целей вам нужна информация из какого источника этот стек. Подробнее пожалуйста второй вопрос изложите его в **другом** вопросе.

Comment: а вопрос 2 дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862155/Можно-ли-динамически-определить-как-был-создан-объект-на-куче-или-в-стеке/862158#862158

Comment: @VTT исправил свой вопрос. Однако в  [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862155/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5/862158#862158) речь о другом. Там нужно определить "местонахождение" объекта, когда нет доступа к коду. К слову, я нашёл решение

Comment: Ответ в любом случае будет одинаковым: по указателю на объект определить его "местонахождение" (а также валидность и удаляемость) нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос 0: хранение ссылки на объект с возможностью ребиндинга достигается посредством `std::reference_wrapper`

```
::std::reference_wrapper<A const> m_a_ref;

B(A const & a): m_a_ref{a} {}
auto Get_A(void) const noexcept -> A const & { return m_a_ref.get(); }
auto Set_A(A const & a) noexcept -> void { m_a_ref = ::std::reference_wrapper<A const>{a}; }
```

Comment: 1. Ненужно указывать ссылку в типе, это уже ссылка, т.е. `reference_wrapper<const A>`. 2. Для создания объектов есть функции `ref`/`cref`, чтобы не повторять тип без надобности.